# Result set code doesn't get executed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, resultset

I've got the following code to query a database! But the code inside the while loop doesn't get executed! No messagebox, just doesn't get executed! Can anyone help me! Result set is not empty! When I print the same value out of the try catch block it gets executed and the right values get printed! Th DB connection is a standard MySQL DB connection class!

```
database = new DBConnection();

    String dept = txtSearch.getText();
    String Query = "SELECT * FROM department where dept_name= '" + dept + "'";

    ResultSet set = database.queryDatabase(Query);

    try {
        if (set.next() == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Matchs found for the search query! Try Again.", "Search Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            while (set.next()) {
                System.out.print(set.getString("dept_name"));
                txtName.setText(set.getString("dept_name"));
                txtDes.setText(set.getString("dept_desc"));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause().toString(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're throwing out the first row of your query by calling `set.next()` and then ignoring the data in the row here:

```
    if (set.next() == false) {  // ***** here on this line
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Matchs found for the search query! 
            Try Again.", "Search Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        while (set.next()) {
            System.out.print(set.getString("dept_name"));
            txtName.setText(set.getString("dept_name"));
            txtDes.setText(set.getString("dept_desc"));
        }
    }
```

Instead be sure to extract information from your ResultSet every time you call `next()` and it returns true.

You could do something like this instead:

```
int setCount = 0;
while (set.next()) {
  setCount++;
  System.out.print(set.getString("dept_name"));
  txtName.setText(set.getString("dept_name"));
  txtDes.setText(set.getString("dept_desc"));
}
if (setCount == 0) {
  // show a warning to the user that the result set was empty
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Although I want the check condition and I found another way to get around it! :) Thank you!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri: You're welcome! How do you check that the ResultSet isn't empty?

Comment: I don't check the result set. instead I check whether the text field is empty!